# jquery confirm not working in js function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

When I submit the form I am checking the validations. If validation `true` then I need to show confirmation. Currently, it is not showing. When validation `true` not shown confirmation, the form is submitted.

**here is my js code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reason').keyup(function () {
            var val = $('#reason').val();
            if (val == null || val == "") {
                $('#reason_error').html('Please provide a reason.');
                validation = false;
            } else {
                $('#reason_error').html('');
            }
        });    
    });


function finishCancelValidate() {
    var validation = true;

    var val = $('#reason').val();
    if (val == null || val == "") {
        $('#reason_error').html('Please provide a reason.');
        validation = false;
    } else {
        $('#reason_error').html('');
    }
    if (validation) {
        //alert('hi');
        jQuery.confirm({
            text: "Do you want to proceed this ?",
            confirm: function () {
                console.log("You just confirmed.");
                return false;
            },
            cancel: function () {
                console.log("You just cancel.");
            }
        });
    } else {
        return validation;
    }
}
```

**this is form tag :**

```
<form method="post" class="register" action="finishController.php?a=cancel" name="cancel" onsubmit="return finishCancelValidate();" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: no errors @Jaromanda X